# Crop or overlay the polygon in the face mask from input image to the output form factor

Tags: python, opencv

I have 3 sample images where I need to produce the input in the form of output image.

Sample image: [image: input image]

Input image when colored:
[image: colored input image]

Sample output image:
[image]

What would be best approach to deal with this problem?

I tried using contours and area having the highest contour and crop that area. But, I didn't get my desired output.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

face_mask = cv2.imread('data/mask5.png')

face_mask = cv2.cvtColor(face_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

gray_mask = cv2.cvtColor(face_mask, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# binary threshold
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray_mask, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contour_list = []
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 2000:
        print(area)
        contour_list.append(c)


# draw contours
img = cv2.drawContours(face_mask, contour_list, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: the black lines representing the mask are too thin to easily segment. I tried a few methods and none of them give good enough results. If you can id suggest making the lines thicker, although that doesnt help you extract them now..

Comment: The lines can be thicker, as the sample input image is a little dreaded. However, is there a way where I can extract the polygon based on geometry? @Ta946

Comment: matching such a shape is hard because your images will not be exactly the same size, shape or rotation because of the deformation from coloring. you would need some advanced methods, atleast from my knowledge. using template matching i was able to get a decent result when the shape is exactly the same, but if the shape is slightly different it wasnt a very clean result. https://imgur.com/a/6uzytko. Your best bet is to have larger black borders that you can extract easily using thresholding or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to add my code that will work only in best case scenarios, incase it helps, I really doubt it will generalize well

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('fOSbn.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

template_left = cv2.imread('template_left.png')
template_right = cv2.imread('template_right.png')

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')

for template in [template_left,template_right]:
    template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # template_gray = cv2.dilate(template_gray, np.ones((3,3),'uint8'), iterations=1)

    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(template_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnt = cnts[0]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    # offset = 10
    # x1 = max(0,x-offset)
    # y1 = max(0,y-offset)
    # x2 = min(img.shape[1],x+w+offset)
    # y2 = min(img.shape[0],y+h+offset)
    x1,y1 = x,y
    x2 = x+w
    y2 = y+h
    bbox = [x1,y1,x2,y2]
    # roi = template[int(bbox[1]):int(bbox[3]),int(bbox[0]):int(bbox[2])]
    roi_gray = template_gray[int(bbox[1]):int(bbox[3]),int(bbox[0]):int(bbox[2])]
    cv2.imshow('roi_gray', roi_gray)

    morph_k = 3
    blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, np.ones((morph_k,morph_k)))
    blackhat = cv2.dilate(blackhat, np.ones((7,7),'uint8'), iterations=1)

    templated = cv2.matchTemplate(blackhat, roi_gray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(templated)

    x1,y1 = max_loc
    x2 = x1+roi_gray.shape[1]
    y2 = y1+roi_gray.shape[0]
    bbox = [x1,y1,x2,y2]

    mask_side = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
    mask_side[int(bbox[1]):int(bbox[3]),int(bbox[0]):int(bbox[2])][roi_gray.view('bool')] = 255
    
    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mask_side, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, 255, -1)
# cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

dst = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

you will need the following images template_left.png and template_right.png

[image: template_left.png]
[image: template_right.png]

this is the result i got

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty good to me, I am thinking if I can use this result and superimpose with that of template image so that we have a fixed mask area and get what's inside mask as well. Making it look like the output image.

Comment: Also, how did you generate both the template images?

Comment: @AnkitKumar i manually traced the lines in the image using paint . i was going to use your first sample image but it was a different shape.
As for separating them, ive added both sides of the mask to the same image, but you can add them to separate images then just shift them abit then combine to new image